# Appium can not start Mainactivity / Splashscreen

Tags: java, android, appium, robotframework, appium-android

I have this script in Java :

```
import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.internal.MouseAction.Button;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidElement;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.AndroidMobileCapabilityType;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType;

public class PABT_Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException {

         File appDir = new File("src");
         File app = new File(appDir, "me.user.myapp.apk");

        DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
    cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "9889db344647575839");
        //cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "9889db344647575839");
//      cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, app.getAbsolutePath());
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, app.getAbsolutePath());
//      cap.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.APP_WAIT_ACTIVITY, "me.user.*");
//      cap.setCapability("appActivity", "md56babf71b8936f51000b2474a3f146837.SplashActivity");
//      cap.setCapability("waitForAppScript","$.delay(100); true;");
//      cap.setCapability("appWaitActivity", "md56babf71b8936f51000b2474a3f146837.SplashActivity, " + "md56babf71b8936f51000b2474a3f146837.MainActivity" );
        AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver = new AndroidDriver<AndroidElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),cap);
        AndroidElement Skip =driver.findElementByLinkText("Skip");
        Skip.click();
        driver.wait(3000);

    }
}
```

I tried to do it in robot framework as well . The code is as follows:

```
*** Settings ***
Library           AppiumLibrary

*** Variables ***
${App_PA}       C:/Android/me.user.myapp.apk

*** Test Cases ***
   Open_App
    ${App}    Set Variable    ${App_PA}
    Open Application    http://localhost:4723/wd/hub    platformName=Android    platformVersion=7.0    deviceName=9889db344647575839    app=${App}    automationName=appium
    sleep    1s
    Click Text    Next
    sleep    1s
    Click Text    Next
    sleep    1s
    Click Text    Get Started
    Wait Until Page Contains    Main Menu
```

In both cases I get the same error that

```
 [ADB] Running 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe' with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","9889db344647575839","shell","dumpsys","window"]
    [AndroidDriver] Screen already unlocked, doing nothing
    [ADB] Device API level: 24
        [ADB] Getting connected devices...
        [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
        [ADB] Running 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe' with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","9889db344647575839","shell","am","start","-W","-n","me.user.myapp/md56babf71b8936f51000b2474a3f146837.SplashActivity","-S"]
        [ADB] Waiting up to 20000ms for activity matching pkg: 'me.user.myapp' and activity: 'md56babf71b8936f51000b2474a3f146837.SplashActivity' to be focused
        [ADB] Possible activities, to be checked: 'md56babf71b8936f51000b2474a3f146837.SplashActivity'
        [ADB] Getting focused package and activity
        [ADB] Getting connected devices...
        [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
        [ADB] Running 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe' with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","9889db344647575839","shell","dumpsys","window","windows"]
        [ADB] Found package: 'me.user.myapp' and fully qualified activity name : 'md56babf71b8936f51000b2474a3f146837.MainActivity'
        [ADB] Incorrect package and activity. Retrying.
        [ADB] Getting focused package and activity
        [ADB] Getting connected devices...
        [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
        ....
        [AndroidDriver] Shutting down Android driver
        [ADB] Getting connected devices...
        [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
        [ADB] Running 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe' with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","9889db344647575839","shell","am","force-stop","me.user.myapp"]
        [ADB] Pressing the HOME button
        [ADB] Getting connected devices...
        [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
```

I have searched SO and other resources and based on the feedback I have done testing .. you can see my failed attempts in the commented out sections of the Java code.

Updated with adb direct execution:

I run the following command and the app gets loaded but I am not able to replicate this success on java or robot

```
c:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools>adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n me.user.myapp/md56babf71b8936f51000b2474a3f146837.SplashActivity
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cmp=me.user.myapp/md56babf71b8936f51000b2474a3f146837.SplashActivity launchParam=MultiScreenLaunchParams { mDisplayId=0 mBaseDisplayId=0 mFlags=0 } }
```

On the other hand, running this command actually fails to launch the app when activity is set to "MainActivity" and shows permission denied error.

```
c:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools>adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n me.user.myapp/md56babf71b8936f51000b2474a3f146837.MainActivity
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cmp=me.user.myapp/md56babf71b8936f51000b2474a3f146837.MainActivity launchParam=MultiScreenLaunchParams { mDisplayId=0 mBaseDisplayId=0 mFlags=0 } }
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN flg=0x10000000 cmp=me.user.myapp/md56babf71b8936f51000b2474a3f146837.MainActivity launchParam=MultiScreenLaunchParams { mDisplayId=0 mBaseDisplayId=0 mFlags=0 } } from null (pid=2984, uid=2000) not exported from uid 10497
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1693)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1646)
    at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivityAsUser(ActivityManagerNative.java:3603)
    at com.android.commands.am.Am.runStart(Am.java:663)
    at com.android.commands.am.Am.onRun(Am.java:392)
    at com.android.internal.os.BaseCommand.run(BaseCommand.java:51)
    at com.android.commands.am.Am.main(Am.java:125)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:316)
```

Comment: What happens if you try launching that activity in the apk using just ABD commands? Do the activities get launched?

Comment: I tried using two commands and adding the feedback on the main question body

Comment: Can you please post the manifest of your app if that is possible? Does it work on another device/emulator?

Comment: No I do not have the manifest  of the app.

Answer (score 0):

Do one thing, just ask the developer to provide the launcher activity for the application. Last week i was having the same issue with an Android app, the problem was the activity that i thought would be the launch activity was not the one. The launch-activity was something else. So just clarify with the developer once.

Came via Upwork

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
adb shell pm dump PACKAGE_NAME
```

This will give you the exact package name and list of activities of application. 
Package mentioned in configuration looks obfuscate, Please check the logs of appium for more details on this issue.

```
cap.setCapability("appActivity", "md56babf71b8936f51000b2474a3f146837.SplashActivity");
```

You can verify the activity using adb activity manager (adb shell am)

Answer (score 0):

in your robotframework code can you try with below capabilities, i see there is no  appPackage and appActivity capabilities .

```
${androiddriver}=    Open Application    http://localhost:4723/wd/hub   platformName=android    platformVersion=7.0    deviceName=9889db344647575839    automationName=uiautomator2
    ...    appPackage=me.user.myapp   newCommandTimeout=2500    appActivity=md56babf71b8936f51000b2474a3f146837.SplashActivity    noReset=True    app=${App}
```